# Function waits for another function to partially complete

Tags: python, wait

P.S. My code is much longer and I have isolated the relevant part of the code. Let me know if more context would help and I can update it.

I have 2 separate functions which are sequencially called ProcessPool (i.e. running simultaneously).
Function 1 create a csv, waits for information to come in and writes to it.
Function 2 reads above csv file and does some calculation and gives the information to Function 1.

Sometimes, function 1 is slow to create the file and function 2 throws an error due to the missing file. Is it possible to make python delay the calling of function 2 till function 1 has finished creating the file? I have been using a naiive time.wait(5) to overcome this. A sample pseudo code is below.

```
def Function1():
    makecsv()
    Tell_Function2_to_start()
    DoOtherStuff()
    return

def Function2():
    DoStuff()
    wait_for_Function1_tells_me_to_start()
    readcsv()
    DoOtherStuff()
    return

# Main function below
Call Function1(), Function2() in parallel
```

Comment: Why are you running them in parallel if one depends on the output of the other?

Comment: If you really have to do something like this, then use a synchronization primitive such as a `Condition` to ensure you don't execute out of order. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-primitives

Comment: Function1 is meant to be a dedicated process to handle writing to the csv file. Since the csv file is common to the multiple parallell Function2, which are trying to write to the same csv. This was the approach i used to syncronize the data between the various runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a Event should help. `Function2` is waiting for notices from `Function1` that event is set, i.e., csv is prepared.

```
from multiprocessing import Event
event = Event()
def Function1():
    makecsv()
    event.set()
    DoOtherStuff()
    return

def Function2():
    DoStuff()
    event.wait()
    readcsv()
    DoOtherStuff()
    return

# Main function below
Call Function1(), Function2() in parallel
```

Comment: Don't use a lock here. You don't have any guarantee that one function will start before the other. A `multiprocessing.Event` would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: @flakes thanks, changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: I had an issue with this method but i found a work around.  Since the event was nested in another function, this didnt work. I solved this by putting Event() in main (as a global) and called __main__.event.set() and __main__.event.wait() in the Functions. That solved the problem